# Sharepoint 2010 workflow impersonation step equivalent in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I'd like to restrict acces to certain items, to certain users, in my sharepoint online list.

I know in List Settings you can restrict access to items only created by user, but this is not enough for me. We have other conditions.

I am currently using Sharepoint Designer, and a sharepoint 2010 workflow with an impersonation step to do Achive this item level permission. this works fine.

However, the end of support for sharepoint 2010 and Designer is scheduled on October 21 2020.

So I have 2 questions:

1) What else could I use in Sharepoint Online to set item level permissions like what I can do with The actions inside an impersonation step with a 2010 workflow?

2) Even though support will end for SP2010 and 2013. will old workflows still work in sharepoint Online sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Power Automate/flow is the alternative for workflow. You could use Auotmate/flow to set item level permssion.

2.Yes, old workflows will still work in SharePoint Online sites.